# Ember.js prevent Google Maps API from loading multiple times

Tags: ember.js

Working with two separate Google maps addons [ember-g-map](https://github.com/asennikov/ember-g-map) and [ember-place-autocomplete](https://github.com/dmuneras/ember-place-autocomplete) which causes this error:

`You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.`

Makes sense, since my index.html page now has multiple scripts loaded in.

Anyone know how Ember devs normally deal with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally the addon author should provide a config option to allow the consumer to include or exclude the Google Maps library. I just submitted a [PR to ember-place-autocomplete](https://github.com/dmuneras/ember-place-autocomplete/pull/32) that does just that. Once the PR gets merged you can use that, or use my forked version.

As an alternative to ember-g-map you might consider using [ember-leaflet](http://www.ember-leaflet.com/) with the ember-leaflet-google-tile-layer addon. Ember-leaflet seems to be the main mapping addon for Ember and it does give the option to exclude the Google maps library.

Comment: Thanks for doing that Steve!